# Buffer queue in router/switch

Tags: networking, queue, switch-statement, buffer, router

I'm so confused of understanding buffer queue concept in router/switch.

Normally, when 2 hosts connected to a same switch with the same delay, link of host1 and switch has bandwidth BW1 and link of host2 and switch has bandwidth BW2.

Host1 send packets continuously to host2.

- If `bw1 = bw2` then when packet come to router, it immediately switch packet to host2. That means router doesn't need a buffer queue, right???
- if `bw1 > bw2` then sending rate is bigger than receiving rate, and router has to keep some packets in buffer queue.

I wonder what is really buffer queue. Is queue concept different to buffer concept?

Please help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Even if the bandwidths of both the links are same, the router needs to do some processing on the packet.

- It extracts the IP headers and looks at the destination IP address.
- It looks up the routing table and finds the next hop that it needs to send the packet.
- Reconstructs the packet and sends it to the next hop.

So there is some processing overhead and if packets arrive faster than the router can process them, then it needs to buffer the packets.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. the rate that router process each packet is pretty fast then even when both links have the same bandwidth, there is still delay and router still has to buffer some packets.